# UNC file shares - use domain name or computer?

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

If I have two server 2008 domain servers and was wondering what happens if I use the domain in the UNC path instead of the computer name?

For example:

\\myserver1\files\myfiles

or

\\myserver2\files\myfiles

vs

\\mydomain.local\files\myfiles

How is it determined which server that the workstation actually connects to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the domain name would only work if you're trying to reach either a) a DFS share, or b) the SYSVOL or NETLOGON folders.

Other than that, if you're looking to files stored on a particular server, use the servers name.

Comment: Correct in a sense. You land on a random domain controller (it's a round-robin DNS entry), and it COULD have a DFS namespace installed. Not everyone installs DFS namespace on all domain controllers :)

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that in a DFS configuration, DFS will use AD to determine which server is closest to you, and connect to that one. If they're both located at your local site, it's a crap shoot, really, and you won't know for sure until you're already connected.

Comment: I... was trying to say that. lol. But what he's describing in his post is exactly how someone would navigate to a DFS share. :)

Comment: That answers this question, and the next question I had concerning DFS. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!